# How to find and replace the character "*" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I am trying to find and replace the `*` (star, or shift+8) character in a bunch of formulas in Excel 2007.  `*` of course matches the ENTIRE contents of the cell, which is not what I want.  How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Find and Replace (`CTRL + H`)

Search for `~*`

Replace with whatever.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 Hit Ctrl-H, Put `~*` in the Find field and `+` in the replace, and it changed the formula. Very nice.

Comment: @Zach, glad to help.

Comment: @iDevlop Sorry for the delay-- I thought I up voted an accepted yesterday, but I guess I forgot the second part!

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in code, you can look for CHAR(42), which is the numeric code for the `*` symbol.

Depending on how you do it, you should even be able to use the CHAR(42) in a worksheet formula.