# How to find and replace a "*" character in a cell without deleting the entire contents in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, find-and-replace

I have a large spreadsheet with a number of cells containing text that have a "*" character at the end. I would like to find and replace this character and delete it. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/486297/how-to-find-and-replace-the-character-in-excel) solution doesn't seem to work in Excel 2010.

Comment: It should work that way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631723/how-to-remove-the-character-in-excel-2010

Comment: Apologies. It does work. It was my pesky Danish keyboard!

Comment: Feel free to remove the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Replace function by pressing CTRL + H and searching for ~* replacing with a blank.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631723/how-to-remove-the-character-in-excel-2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RANGE,"*","")
```

You could definitely put a cell range in there, such as:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1:Z2000,"*","")
```

And I suspect you could put a worksheet name in there?